# How do you limit a Mac Finder search to only show .jar files?

Tags: macos, finder

While trying to find specific `.jar` files using the Mac Finder, I cannot limit the search criteria (an option found by clicking the settings gear icon and then `Show Search Criteria` by `Kind` of `.jar`.

While trying setting `Kind` to `Other` and using `.jar` or `*.jar`, no results are returned for jar files that I know exist on my computer. I have tried the same for `.tar` as well.

Is there a way to limit a Finder search to specific jar files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost, the literal *kind* of .jar files is `Java JAR file`

[image]

You can check the Spotlight attributes of a file yourself pretty simply.

- Open Terminal.app.
- Type `mdls` followed by a space character.
- Drag the file into the Terminal window.
- Press <kbd>return</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like `jar` aside from `Java JAR file` works as well

Answer (score 0):

After selecting a New Smart folder from the finders file menu. Using the criteria lines can contain multiple statements by clicking the plus button.

Additionally if you hold down the option key, the plus turns into an options statement in which you can select additional criteria such as "all the following are true or false"

You can create multiple condition criteria using this method. You might need to logically experiment with where you place the statements in such a way it returns what's expected. As the order in which you create them is the order the machine goes through the workflow.